# Random xml layouts files for an Activity

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, random, android-activity

I have five layouts(XML files), each one with a `Button` on it and two activities, A & B. In the `onClick` action of start Button in A, I'll open the activity B  and all the story begins there:

In my activity B, first, I want to show one of these five xml files **and `onclick` of the `Button` IN each of the five XML files, I want to randomly open the remaining 4 xml files, until Back button is pressed.**. Is there any way I could do this or I must have 5 activities each with one layout?

My problem is:

**Just one Xml file is appearing randomly on activity B and the `Button` on that xml file is not responding, i.e, not showing next xml file.**

Here is the code for my activity B:

```
public class B extends Activity {
Handler handler = new Handler();
Button bt;

int[] layouts = {R.layout.first,R.layout.second,R.layout.third,R.layout.fourth,R.layout.fifth};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    bt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    for (int i = 0; i < layouts.length; i++) {


                        setContentView(layouts[rand]);
                    }

                }
            }, 2000);

        }
    });


}
```

And all the 5 Xml Files Will go in the same paTTERN:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:onClick="showLayouts"
    android:text="5th" />
```

I am new to Java, So Stucked Here, If any simple clue also will help me.I have searched this forum And found no relevant solution.

@LuksProg, Logcat Error is Like this:

```
  **03-11 05:51:16.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1575): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 03-11 05:51:16.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1575): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.SAI.wth/com.SAI.wth.ReceivingActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
 03-11 05:51:16.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1575):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
 03-11 05:51:16.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1575):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
 03-11 05:51:16.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1575):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
 03-11 05:51:16.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1575):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
 03-11 05:51:16.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1575):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 03-11 05:51:16.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1575):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 03-11 05:51:16.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1575):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
 03-11 05:51:16.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1575):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 03-11 05:51:16.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1575):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 03-11 05:51:16.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1575):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
 03-11 05:51:16.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1575):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
 03-11 05:51:16.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1575):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 03-11 05:51:16.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1575): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 03-11 05:51:16.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1575):    at com.SAI.wth.ReceivingActivity.onCreate(ReceivingActivity.java:40)
 03-11 05:51:16.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1575):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
 03-11 05:51:16.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1575):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
 03-11 05:51:16.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1575):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)**
```

This time I want to do this,

```
    switch (mPosition) {
                            case R.layout.first:
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "First", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                break;

                            case R.layout.second:
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "second", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//Some sound                                
                                break;

                            case R.layout.third:
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "third", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //Some media , Different for each Layout..                          
                                break;  

                            case R.layout.fourth:
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "fourth", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                break;

                            case R.layout.fifth:
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "fifth", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                break;  
                            default:
                                break;
                            }


                            Collections.shuffle(mLayouts);
                        }
                        mPosition = 0;
                    }
```

Comment: So what happens when you run this code?

Comment: just one Xml file is Appearing in random & the button on that xml file is not responding, i.e, not showing next xml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> just one Xml file is Appearing in random on Activity B & the button on
>   that xml file is not responding, i.e, not showing next xml file.

You'll want something like this:

```
private int mPosition = 0;
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private List<Integer> mLayouts;
private Button mButton;

private OnClickListener mListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // as you're posting this delayed you may want to make sure the 
                // user doesn't click this Buton again in the two seconds interval
                if (mPosition >= mLayouts.size()) { // revert the list
                    int lastId = mLayouts.get(mLayouts.size() - 1);
                    Collections.shuffle(mLayouts);
                    // do this so if we randomize the layouts we don't end
                    // up after the shuffle with the same layout on the
                    // first
                    // position as the last position
                    while (lastId == mLayouts.get(0)) {
                        Collections.shuffle(mLayouts);
                    }
                    mPosition = 0;
                }
                setContentView(mLayouts.get(mPosition));
                mPosition++;
                mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnId);
                mButton.setOnClickListener(mListener);
            }

        }, 2000);           
    }

};
```

and in the `onCreate` method:

```
    mLayouts = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    mLayouts.add(R.layout.layout1);
    mLayouts.add(R.layout.layout2);
    mLayouts.add(R.layout.layout3);
    mLayouts.add(R.layout.layout4);
    mLayouts.add(R.layout.layout5);
    Collections.shuffle(mLayouts);
    setContentView(mLayouts.get(mPosition));
    mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnId);
    mButton.setOnClickListener(mListener);
    mPosition++;
```

Comment: HI,@Luksprog, Thanks for the edit & the Reply, It is showing "NullPointer Exception"And the Logcat error is shown above in the edited question.Plz check it...

Comment: @sai Something is null in your code at line `40` in your `onCreate` method. My code should work with no problems. Are you sure you have the same button id for all the layouts?

Comment: Yeah @Luksprog, Some small error , I rectified it. now it is working.But it is showing only one layout(in Random)."OnClick"ing of the button in that Layout is still & Not changing the Layouts man.

Comment: @sai Ok, I've actually run my code and it works as it should. Are you sure you've setup the layouts alright? Keep in mind that you have a 2 second delay before the layouts change.

Comment: Thanks yo @Luksprog, its working. But it is not repeating the layouts . i.e., it is Shuffling all the 5 xml layouts & after completion of 5 files one time it is just remaining dumb.          "I want to randomly open the remaining 4 xml files, until Back button is pressed.." My requirement is this PLZ

Comment: @sai Ok, just to be sure: do you want the user to be able to click on the `Button` and setup a new layout **only** when he clicks the `Button` or do you want the user to click the `Button` **once** and from that point on the layouts should be changed **automatically** after the set time period?

Comment: Thanks for the reply,The first one is my requirement."If user clicks the button, I'l show an Image & play some sound , All combined for 3 seconds, Then goes to next Layout.There also same procedure, with different Image & different sound"----*****Important requirement is that I should be rotating all the 5 Layouts randomly until the user presses back Button.*****----This is the Scheme PLZ...

Comment: @sai If you want that on clicking the Button to do something then put that something in the `onClick` callback. if you want to do something after the user clicked the Button and the new layout is set then put that something after setting the content view in the Runnable. Anything besides this I can't help you.

Comment: @sai Please start a new question asking what you try to do(providing related details), we can't talk here for ever.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to work just fine when I do this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    Button bt;

    int[] layouts = { R.layout.first, R.layout.second, R.layout.third, R.layout.fourth,
        R.layout.fifth };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.first);

        bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);

        bt.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v.getId() == R.id.button5){

            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                    public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    int rand = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * layouts.length);
                    setContentView(layouts[rand]);


                    bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
                    bt.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);

                }
            }, 2000);

        }

    }
}
```