# Random XML Layout on button click

Tags: java, android, xml, random

I have 20 XML layouts. What I want to happen is to show random xml layouts when the button is clicked. I tried and read [same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15308473/random-xml-layouts-files-for-an-activity) as mine but i didnt worked.

For example in Level1 class when the user clicked the PositiveButton in the AlertDialog, random XML Layout will be opened (Level 20 or Level 15 not Level 2).

This is code in Level1 class(the same pattern applies for the rest of the classes)

```js
public class Luzon1 extends Activity {
 private String [] answers;
 private Button answerButton;
 private TextView scoreTxt, showClue;
 private EditText answerText;
 int scoreNew=0;
 public Button yes;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_luzon1);


 }
 public void init()
 {
 //correct answer
 answers=new String[]{"Tarlac"};
 
(R.id.AnswerButton);
 answerButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   checkAnswer();
  }
 });
 }
 
 public boolean isCorrect(String answer)
 { return(answer.equalsIgnoreCase(answers[currentQuestion])); }

 public void checkAnswer()
 { String answer=answerText.getText().toString(); 
 
  if(isCorrect(answer))
  {  
   
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Congratulations! You will receive P10!");
            builder.setMessage("Did you know that Former bla bla bla Did you know that Former bla bla bla Did you know that Former bla bla bla");
            builder.setIcon(android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_on);
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                
          String userData=scoreTxt.getText().toString();
    int userNumber=Integer.parseInt(userData);
             
    Intent intent=new Intent(Luzon1.this, Luzon2.class);
    intent.putExtra("parameter name", userNumber);
    startActivity(intent);
             Luzon1.this.finish(); System.exit(0);
             
             } });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
      alert.show(); // Show Alert Dialog
```

Thank you so much in advance. and any code snippet will be a great help.

Comment: Are you referring to the XML layout for the activity? And is this changed within your `onClick` method?

Comment: yes im referring to xml layout. when the button is clicked level 2 is opened.

Comment: where do you want to set this layouts ? post the relevant code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Setting the layout from inside `onClick()`

If you want this code to be in the `onClick()` method in your previous activity (the one shown above), use the following code:

```
@Override
protected void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    Random generator = new Random(); 
    int number = generator.nextInt(NUMBER_OF_LEVELS) + 1;

    Class activity;

    switch(number) {
        case 1:
            activity = LevelOne.class;
            break;
        case 2:
            activity = LevelTwo.class;
            break;
        case 3:
            activity = LevelThree.class;
            break;
        case 4:
            activity = LevelFour.class;
            break;
        case 5:
            activity = LevelFive.class;
            break;

        ...

        case 20:
            activity = LevelTwenty.class;
            break;
    }

    Intent intent = (getBaseContext(), activity);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: this is clear. but the level2 class and xml layout will be opened. what i want to happen is open random xml layout for example level20, or level18 or level5.

Comment: So, in your Level2 class, a random level layout would be opened.

Comment: can i put the code inside the positive button of alert dialog?

Comment: I've edited my answer again - is this what you meant?

Comment: yes. my last question will be is the code above will make random layout when the button is clicked?

Comment: It won't __make__ a random layout but the layouts I mentioned above (like `LEVEL_ONE_XML`, `LEVEL_TWO_XML`, etc.) would be layouts that you've already created. So, it would __use__ a layout that you've already created in your app.

Comment: thank you for posting your code. but can you help me to create random layout once the user clicked the button? i dont want to open the layout consecutively..

Comment: What do you mean by 'create random layout'?

Comment: For example in Level1 class when the user clicked the button, random XML Layout will be opened (Level 20 or Level 15 XML Layout & class not Level 2).

Comment: So you want the class that is opened to be random when the button is pressed, meaning that it would open a random layout/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Declare a public static int count = 0 before onCreate..
then, In onClick increment the count by 1(count++)..
Use switch statement like,(Dont forget to reset counter to 0 when count becomes 20)

```
void onClick(){
      count++;

      switch(count) {
             case 1:
                   setContentView(R.layout.yourLayout1);
                   break;
             case 2:

                   setContentView(R.layout.yourLayout2);
                   break;
             case 3:
                   setContentView(R.layout.yourLayout3);
                   break;                 
             case 4:
                   setContentView(R.layout.yourLayout4);
                      ................................
                      ................................
             case 20:
                   setContentView(R.layout.yourLayout20);
                   break;                     
            }
      if(count==20){
          count = 0;
}

}
```

And also instead of incrementing count each time user clicks, you can use `Math.random()` and assign it to `count`  (Remember to check(use if statement) `Math.random()` is returning a value which is below or equal to 20..)

Hope it will help you..